# AssertionError: <class 'method'> when trying to add two pandas df columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I did the following to add to the existing df

```
df['std'] = df[df['growth'].notnull()].groupby('id')['growth'].transform('std').astype(float)
```

my df is

```
id  growth   std
A    0.2    0.124
A    0.3    0.124
A    0.5    0.124
B     1     0.216
B    0.5    0.216
B    0.6    0.216
C
...
```

then i did the following

```
df['ratio'] = df.growth / df.std
```

which should be a simple task but i get the following error msg. I am so confused as to why?

Here is the full traceback.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in na_op(x, y)
    967         try:
--> 968             result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, x, y, **eval_kwargs)
    969         except TypeError:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, use_numexpr, **eval_kwargs)
    220     if use_numexpr:
--> 221         return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
    222     return _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py in _evaluate_standard(op, op_str, a, b, **eval_kwargs)
     69     with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
---> 70         return op(a, b)
     71 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'method'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
: <class 'method'>
```

I checked `dtype` and `std`, `growth` are both float???

Comment: Please post the full traceback…

Comment: Still not the full traceback…?!

Comment: Something that should start with the text "`Traceback (most recent call last)`", and then lists a bunch of informative lines of code that lead to the error. That's typically what you see by default on any exception… How are you executing this code?

Comment: `... .groupby('id')'growth'] ...`  does not seem right?

Comment: that was a typo.

Comment: @deceze pls see above.

Comment: I am not sure why it is saying my "std" variable is method???????? So strange. I don't even understand what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) is built-in method, use `[]` for indexing columns in this case

```py
df['ratio'] = df['growth'] / df['std']
```